# I cannot run python on vscode because my computer believes that my .py file is untrusted

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Previously I had python running just fine in VSCode but recently something has gone wrong and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

When I open a .py file (downloaded from an email) in VSCode I get a message saying that this source is not trusted. I then followed through the suggestions and made the file trusted and I get a box saying that all extensions are enabled. However, when I try and run it, the box is still blurred out

[image: blurred out run button]

This is the error I get when I try and run the whole file, not just the cell.

[image]

Does someone know how to get this up and running first? Thanks

Comment: Did you download and install python? Did you add python to environment variables?

Comment: The issue you are having is unclear, but the "python was not found" message suggests that you need to make sure it is properly installed.

Comment: before opening a .py file try to run python and check python is installed or in the path

Comment: This is what is strange, when I run python in a new file it works fine, it's just when I download a .pynb (sorry I know I said .py in the original q) from an email that it VScode won't accept that I want to trust the file which means I cannot run the code. I have also installed the Jupyter extension so that should work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comment and say it is .ipynb file, you only need to enter the trusted file name on the command line of Jupiter notebook
"$ jupyter trust 'filename'.ipynb"
This is a link to instructions:https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook.html#trusting-notebooks